# Javascript call function at each "X" minutes by clock

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clock

Ok, so I have:

```
function show_popup() {
    alert('Ha');
}
```

Now, what I want is to call this function at each **X** minutes **BUT** giving as reference the clock (the real time).

If **X** is 5, then the next function works properly:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var date = new Date();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes().toString();
    var minutes = minutes.slice(-1); // Get last number

    if(minutes == 0 || minutes == 5)
    {
        show_popup(); // This will show the popup at 00:00, 00:05, 00:10 and so on
    }
}, 1000);
```

How can I make this function to work if I change 5 minutes to 4, or to 3, or to 20 ?

I must mention that I can't change the timer from setinterval, cause this it will mean that the popup will trigger only if you are on page AFTER passing X minutes. I don't want that. I want to show the popup at specific minutes giving the reference the clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the [multiples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_(mathematics)) of **X**

To do that, you can use [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), so:

```
if(minutes % X === 0) {
  show_popup();
}
```

The modulo operation will return the **rest of division** between **a** and **b**, if thats 0, thats means **b** is **multiple** of **a**.

For example, if you want to show every 3 minutes:

```
1 % 3 = 1
2 % 3 = 2
3 % 3 = 0 //show
4 % 3 = 1
5 % 3 = 2
6 % 3 = 0 //show
```

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

two ways, just run the code to see results(in chrome browser)

1.use timer and you can change period when next tick comes, timer is not that precise

```js
class MyInterval {
  constructor(defaultInterval, callback) {
    this.interval = defaultInterval
    this.callback = callback
    this._timeout = null
    this.tick()
  }

  tick() {
    const {
      interval,
      callback
    } = this
    this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      callback()
      this.tick()
    }, interval)
  }

  stop() {
    clearTimeout(this._timeout)
  }
  changeInterval(interval) {
    this.interval = interval
  }
}

const myInterval = new MyInterval(1000, () => console.log(new Date()))

setTimeout(() => {
  myInterval.changeInterval(2000)
}, 3500)


setTimeout(() => {
  myInterval.stop(2000)
}, 13500)
```

2.use a minimal interval, more quick to react, has a minimal limit, may cost more

```js
class MyInterval {
  constructor(minimal, defaultInterval, callback) {
    this.minimal = minimal
    this.interval = defaultInterval
    this.callback = callback
    this._current = 0
    this._timeout = setInterval(() => {
      this._current++
        if (this._current >= this.interval) {
          this._current = 0
          callback()
        }

    }, minimal)


  }
  stop() {
    clearInterval(this._timeout)
  }
  changeInterval(interval) {
    this.interval = interval
  }
}

const myInterval = new MyInterval(1000, 1, () => console.log(new Date()))

setTimeout(() => {
  myInterval.changeInterval(2)
}, 3500)


setTimeout(() => {
  myInterval.stop()
}, 13500)
```